# Entity Detach and Merge inside EntityListener causes possible non thread safe access to session

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I defined a custom EntityListener for a given Entity. The EntityListener wants to compare the modified entity against the entity from database.
I am using the EntityManager to detach the received entity as parameter and load the original entity. After the comparison is done I am attaching back the modified entity to the EntityManager.

The above flow causes error:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convertCommitException(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:104)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:562)
    ... 144 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: possible non thread safe access to session
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:215)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:478)
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:721)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:475)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:344)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1407)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:489)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3290)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2425)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:449)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:281)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101)
    ... 145 more
```

The EntityListener is defined in the following:

```
public class ExpoEntityListener2 {

    @Autowired
    private ClientRepository clientRepository;
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @PreUpdate
    public void preUpdate(IdEntity idEntity) {
        if(idEntity instanceof Client) {
            SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);

            entityManager.detach(idEntity);

            Client dbIdEntity = clientRepository.findById(idEntity.getId()).orElse(null);
            //Comparison logic

            entityManager.merge(idEntity);
        }
    }
}
```

How should I avoid this Transacational error?